# Problems with Unity, unable to display raw images with unity on hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

Recently I have working on a project where I am trying to roll images on a hololens using voice commands. In the unity folder, I have created a raw image called dell. However using voice commands I wish to change the raw image to an image called acer. I ran a debugger in visual studios and this is the error that it game me.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SpriteManager.NextImage()
   at SpriteManager.$Invoke0(Int64 instance, Int64* args)
   at UnityEngine.Internal.$MethodUtility.InvokeMethod(Int64 instance, Int64* args, IntPtr method)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SpriteManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject a;
    public Sprite dell;

    //int count = 0;

    void Start () {

    }  
   void NextImage()
    {
        Debug.Log("It's working!");
        GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = a.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I am getting an error after the debug.log()

Dell is a 2d sprite in my unity project I want to change my image too.

Can someone help?